# Add_shortcode as a Class to pass arguments to a function

Tags: shortcode

Bonsoir, I want to pass shortcode attributes to my class in a form of an array and the name of my shorcode but in the wordpress codex doesn't says how could i do that, this is my code

```
 $atributos=array('url' => ' ','text' => ' ');
 $shortcode_name="myshortcode";

 class MyLittleClass {
    public static function exe_short( $atts, $atributos, $shortcode_name) {

     $_atts = shortcode_atts($atributos, $atts );   

     // Attributes turn to variables
        $url = $_atts['url'];
        $text = $_atts['text']; 

        ob_start(); 
        include(ABS_DIR . '/includes/dynamics/'.$shortcode_name.'/index.php');  
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }
 }

add_shortcode( $shortcode_name, array( 'MyPlugin', 'exe_short');
```

I know Im not passing the variables $atributos and $shortcode_name as an argumens for exeshort() in the function add_shortcode() but if i do this

```
add_shortcode( $shortcode_name, array( 'MyPlugin',exe_short($atts, $atributos, $shortcode_name))
```

It doesnt work either, how could I pass those variables to my class function ?

Comment: I believe you need a function outside of the class to add shortcode.  Try removing the class and call a normal function. or encapsulating this whole thing into a function and call the shortcode after.

Comment: but i need to define the same function and unfortunately is in the same script and will have issues, that's why i need a class to call his function and send that function my parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create multiple shortcodes, you can get the default values from a static attribut of the class.
This code create 2 shortcodes `myshortcode1` and `myshortcode2`. In the included files, you can read variables `$_atts`, `$content` and `$tag`

```
class MyLittleClass {

    public static $shortcodes;


    public static function init() {

        self::$shortcodes = [
            "myshortcode1" => [
                "defaultValues" => [
                    "text" => "my link",
                    "url" => home_url("/"),
                ],
            ],
            "myshortcode2" => [
                "defaultValues" => [
                    "color" => "#EEC",
                ],
            ],
        ];


        foreach (array_keys(self::$shortcodes) as $code) {
            add_shortcode($code, [__CLASS__, "exe_short"]);
        }

    }

    public static function exe_short($attr, $content, $tag) {

        $atributos = self::$shortcodes[$tag]["defaultValues"];
        $_atts = shortcode_atts($atributos, $attr, $tag);

        ob_start(); 
        include(ABS_DIR . '/includes/dynamics/'.$tag.'/index.php');  
        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;

    }

}

MyLittleClass::init();
```

you can also create shortcodes in passing an array at `init` or creating a filter when initializing `$shortcodes`.

Comment: I now this space is not made to say thanks but that code is what im looking for, thank you @mmm

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the method `exe_short`, you can create a new method like that

```
class MyLittleClass {

    public static function exe_short2($attr, $content, $tag) {

        $atts = $attr;
        $atributos = ["url" => "", "text" => $content];
        $shortcode_name = $tag;

        return self::exe_short( $atts, $atributos, $shortcode_name);

    }


    public static function exe_short( $atts, $atributos, $shortcode_name) {

        $_atts = shortcode_atts($atributos, $atts );

        // Attributes turn to variables
        $url = $_atts['url'];
        $text = $_atts['text']; 

        ob_start(); 
        include(ABS_DIR . '/includes/dynamics/'.$shortcode_name.'/index.php');  
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;

    }


}

add_shortcode( "myshortcode", array( 'MyPlugin', 'exe_short2');
```

Comment: I wan to do it outside the function in an very good format - Shortcode Name : xxx - Attributes : Array (xxx,xxx,xxx) and then the whole code do the thing, Imagine someone who doesnt know how to code, enters this code and in a manual says, change the shortocode name and the attributes in the array, then add xxx_file.php and with those attributes you define on the shortcode play with them

Comment: I add a new answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284905/add-shortcode-as-a-class-to-pass-arguments-to-a-function/#answer-284994